# What are good online resources for credit portfolio managers?

Tags: risk, portfolio-management, risk-management, credit-risk, soft-question

I am aware that this question is not the typical quant.SE question, BUT I couldn`t find any site/forum/wiki, where credit portfolio managers hang out to share their experience and their methods. Therefore, I am kindly ask you in advance not to downvote or close this question, because I am sure that there is a lot of interest in such a "soft" question.

What are the good online resources for credit portfolio managers?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: do you mean free resources or are you generally asking that for?

Comment: @Quantopic Thx for your reply! If free or not, it does not matter ;). However, I guess many would prefer something close too free.

Comment: please, @Kare mark the answer if you found that useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards the *free* sources, the best place where you can find **material** about credit risk management is [defaultrisk.com](http://defaultrisk.com/); it is a website where are collected (almost) all academic (and not) articles and working paper, references and researchers.

Moreover, as regards the **forums**, I think you should try visiting [Credit Risk Group](https://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=59483&trk=vsrp_groups_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A1595433551427447970817%2CVSRPtargetId%3A59483%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary) at Linkedin; it is a very active group (about 80 conversation per month) where you can post your question/answer with your opinion about credit risk & portfolio management. Again, you can find support here on the quant.stackexchange site too; a lot of people ask for question about credit risk.

No database is free. You can find a lot of data on the internet, but for paying. A great database is [Bankscope](https://bankscope.bvdinfo.com/version-2015325/home.serv?product=scope2006), that is a credit bureau powered by Fitch ratings. You should try that as well as Bloomberg, Datastream Reuters, etc.